# How to retrieve only the month/year in the value in material-ui date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a date picker that I modified to only let the user select month/year. Now, I only want a part of the data(month/year) because it returns something like this

"Thu Feb 18 2010 21:11:54 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)".

I am thinking of putting the whole string in the array and get the indexes of the month and year but before I do that, I want to know if there is a much better and faster way.

Now, what I'm doing is like this

```
const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());

const handleDateChange = (date) => {
   console.log(date);
};

<DatePicker
   variant="inline"
   openTo="year"
   views={["year", "month"]}
   label="Year and Month"
   value={"selectedDate"}
   onChange={handleDateChange}
/>
```

It logs "Thu Feb 18 2010 21:11:54 GMT+0800 (China Standard Time)".
I only want the "Feb 2010".

Answer (score 2):

To store the date as you have detailed in the selectedDate variable, change the handleDateChange function to this.

```
const handleDateChange = (date) => {
  setSelectedDate(new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth()));
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it logs the same thing

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. The same logic worked. I just needed to make it selectedDate.getMonth() and selectedDate.getYear() in my case. Thank you so much man you save me a lot of hours.

Edit. I tried upvoting your answer but it seems that I don't have enough score to do that.

Comment: I have updated the answer to more accurately represent what I meant.

Comment: I'm having a problem in the new handleDateChange function that you specified. 

What happens is that, when I select a month and year only once, it will log the previous date. I need to select the month twice for the console to accurately log the current month that I have selected.

Comment: @captainalbert - I will need to see the code where the `console.log` is run to be able to tell what is happening here.